# Pointing DNS to NationBuilder servers from Network Solutions

Tags: cname, a-record

I own a domain name that is registered at Network Solutions.  They offer me two options to enter for DNS records, `A` and `CNAME`.

The website provider I'm hosted at, NationBuilder.com gives instructions that instruct me to point the Name Servers to five of their name servers as follows:

- `ns10.nationbuilder.com`
- `ns11.nationbuilder.com`
- `ns12.nationbuilder.com`
- `ns13.nationbuilder.com`
- `ns14.nationbuilder.com`
- `ns15.nationbuilder.com`

Anybody know to configure `A` and or `CNAME` records to point to these name servers?  I suspect if I PING the name servers and use the IP address in the results and configure "A" records, something will break down the road since I'm not answering their question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you [added the domain to your NationBuilder account](https://support.nationbuilder.com/en/articles/2886934-connect-a-custom-domain-to-your-nation-while-managing-your-own-dns) there was a checkbox for "NationBuilder should manage this domain".   You must have submitted with this checkbox enabled.  Once you do so, NationBuilder wants to become your DNS host.  It asks you to point your NS records to their DNS servers at your domain registrar.  If you had unchecked this checkbox, NationBuilder would give you a `CNAME` to use.  See the section entitled "Connect a domain managed elsewhere to a site" in the documentation I linked above.

You have two possible courses of action:

1. Remove the domain from your NationBuilder account and re-add while making sure the "NationBuilder should manage this domain" checkbox is unchecked.
2. Change your `NS` records at NetworkSolutions.    You can edit your `NS` records from [Edit DNS](https://www.networksolutions.com/manage-it/dns.jsp) by selecting "Move DNS".  This will change your DNS host from NetworkSolutions to NationBuilder.  Note that NetworkSolutions will still be your domain registrar after this change, they just won't host the DNS for your domain anymore.

To help you understand what is going on, here is a diagram of how DNS records are typically set up for a domain.   In this case your domain registrar is Network Solutions and your website host in NationBuilder.  Both are offering to host your DNS.   You can choose either as your DNS host and there are ways to make it work in either configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Further to what Stephen Ostermiller says.  At Network Solutions:

- Log in to your account
- In the My Products & Services tab under the My Domain Names section, click Edit DNS.
- On the next page in the grey box on the right side, click Domain Name Server (DNS).
- Enter your name servers in the space provided.
- Click Continue when finished making changes.
- Click Apply Changes on the next screen to finalize your new name servers.